# A Set Having More Vectors Than Entries in Each Vector Is Linearly Dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

There is a theorem in linear algebra that seems simple enough to understand. It goes like this.

Theorem: Given a set of $n$ vectors, each with $p$ entries, if $n \gt p$, the set is linearly dependent.

But is the following proof correct and rigorous?

Proof: Let us use the definition of a basis and the definition of a dimension to try and rigorously prove the theorem.

A basis of a $p$-dimensional subspace $H$ is a linearly independent set of vectors than spans $H$.

The dimension of $H$ is the number of vectors in any given basis of $H$.

If $H$ is $p$-dimensional, then both definitions imply that the number of vectors in any basis of $H$ is $p$. So if a set of $n$ vectors in $H$ is linearly independent, $n \leq p$, which can easily be shown.

It's easy to find $n$ vectors in $H$ that are linearly independent when $n\lt p$. Just take $n$ of the $p$ basis vectors of any basis of $H$. Since they're part of a basis, they must be linearly independent. When $n=p$, take any basis of $H$ which, by the definition of a basis, will be made up of $p$ linearly independent vectors.

Now when $n \gt p$, something happens. We have exceeded the number of dimensions which make up $H$. If you add $n-p$ vectors to a linearly dependent set of $p$ vectors in $H$ where $n \gt p$, the theorem is proven. Otherwise, assume that we have a set of $p$ vectors in $H$ that is linearly independent. We need to show that any set of $p$ linearly independent vectors in $H$ is automatically a basis for $H$, which is done in the following manner.

Let us take a set of $p$ linearly independent vectors in $H$. Let us assume that this set of vectors does not span $H$. This implies that we are missing at least one basis vector. But if that's the case, then we should find at least one $u \in H$ that is not a linear combination of the other $p$ vectors. But then the basis would have more than $p$ vectors, which contradicts the fact that $H$ is $p$-dimensional by the definition of a dimension. So a set of $p$ linearly independent vectors in $H$ is automatically a basis for $H$.

By this, any vector in $H$ can be written as a linear combination of $p$ linearly independent vectors in $H$. So if we add $n-p$ vectors that are in $H$ to a set of $p$ linearly independent vectors in $H$ and $n \gt p$, we must have a linearly dependent set no matter what.

**QED**

Comment: I'm hoping that this is correct, this is the most time I've spent on a proof so far.

Comment: This is a result that you should (try to) prove without using the definition of a basis. You can do that by induction on $n$, the number of components of the given vectors. Try first for $n=1$, $n=2$, and see if you can get a proof by induction. The notion of dimension uses this particular result, so you should not go in circles by using it.